# Horizontal Bar Chart D3, .txt file

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I have a dataset called data.txt that looks like the following:

```
{class:'C 1',nums:{A:716, B:1287, C:249}}

,{class:'C 2',nums:{A:2000, B:1876, C:3009}}

,{class:'C 3',nums:{A:899, B:2333, C:418}}
```

I am trying to make a horizontal bar chart with d3 v3 for this data. What I want to do is have the sum of A + B + C be on the bars but when you hover over them the legend shows A, B, C values. I want the labels on this chart to be C 1, C 2, and C 3. I am having trouble reading in this data. I am trying

```
d3.text("data.text",function(d) {
return {
label: d.class, 
Q1: +d.nums[1],
Q2: +d.nums[2],
Q3: +d.nums[3],
Q4: +d.nums[4],
total: Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4        
};
}, function(data) {
console.log(data[0]);
});
```

However, I can't get the data to render at all. 
I have looked here http://learnjsdata.com/read_data.html but this did not help me. I was also going to try and follow this bar chart http://bl.ocks.org/juan-cb/faf62e91e3c70a99a306 and make it look like how I had wanted.

Can anyone please assist me with building this chart and reading this data in. Thank you.

Comment: I also tried 
d3.text("dataset.txt",function(data) {
        data.nums["A"] = +data.nums["A"];
        data.nums["B"] = +data.nums["B"]; 
        data.nums["C"] = +data.nums["C"] 
console.log(data[0]);
});
which did not work for me either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense using that structure in a text file. `d3.text` will not be able to parse it. Since you have objects with nested objects, you may want to use `d3.json` instead.

First, let's transform this data in a valid JSON, transforming it in an array of objects:

```
[
 {"class":"C 1","nums":{"A":716, "B":1287, "C":249}},
 {"class":"C 2","nums":{"A":2000, "B":1876, "C":3009}},
 {"class":"C 3","nums":{"A":899, "B":2333, "C":418}}
]
```

Then, we load it using `d3.json`:

```
d3.json("data.json", function(data){
    //your code here
});
```

But, as you said in the question, you want to use the total of the `nums` object for the bars. We can create another key/value pair named `total`:

```
data.forEach(function(d){
    var values = 0;
    for (var key in d.nums){
        values += d.nums[key]
    }
    d.total = values;
});
```

Now you have everything you need for the bars: `total` will be used for the width and `nums` object for the tooltip.

Here is a demo snippet, using a variable (because it's difficult using an external file in the snippet):

```js
data = [{"class":"C 1","nums":{"A":716, "B":1287, "C":249}}
,{"class":"C 2","nums":{"A":2000, "B":1876, "C":3009}}
,{"class":"C 3","nums":{"A":899, "B":2333, "C":418}}];

data.forEach(function(d){
    var values = 0;
    for (var key in d.nums){
      values += d.nums[key]
    }
    d.total = values;
  });

var div = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

var xScale = scale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })])
            .range([0, 400]);

var svg = d3.select('body')
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 400)
            .attr("height", 400);

var bars = svg.selectAll(".rects")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("rect");

bars.attr("x", 0).attr("y", function(d,i){ return i*50})
 .attr("height", 40)
.attr("fill", "teal")
 .attr("width", function(d){ return xScale(d.total)});

bars.on("mousemove", function(d){
                div.style("left", d3.event.pageX+10+"px").style("top", d3.event.pageY-25+"px").style("display", "inline-block").html("All the values: A=" + d.nums.A + ", B=" + d.nums.B + ", C=" + d.nums.C);
            }).on("mouseout", function(d){
                div.style("display", "none");
            });
```

```css
.toolTip {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you for your great answer I am getting 
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'data.forEach')
when I try the above

Comment: Show exactly what you are doing, because you can see that the snippet is working.

Comment: Ah, I got it to work. Thank you very much. I am trying to get your tooltip to be fixed at the bottom right. Is that possible or can we only make it hover above the bars?

Comment: Yes, it is. I made it above the bars just to show you. You can change the `position` or set fixed coordinates.

Comment: Thank you. I accepted your answer. I am new to D3 but am finding it fun. Last question, where in bars.on("mouse move"..) could I set the position to fixed coordinates to display the tool tip? I know i need to set .attr() and some coordinates but don't know the best place to do so.

Comment: This is more complicated. Here at SO we deal with one question at the time, and we try to avoid Q&A in the comments. As this is another subject, please post another question.